# 'Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined' when using Chart.JS with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I get the error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined' with the following example below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="module" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.3.2/chart.umd.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
<canvas id="myChart" style="max-height:400px; max-width:500px"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getRandomInt(n, min, max) {
      let result = new Array();
      for (let i=0;i<n;i++) {
          min = Math.ceil(min);
          max = Math.floor(max);
          result.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min));
      }
      return result;
    }

    var myChart = document.getElementById('myChart');

    const labels = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul'];
    const data = {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Dataset 1',
          data: this.getRandomInt(7, -100, 100),
          borderColor: '#f22613',
        },
        {
          label: 'Dataset 2',
          data: this.getRandomInt(7, -100, 100),
          borderColor: '#4287f5',
        }
      ]
    };

    const config = { type: 'line', data: data, options: { responsive: true, plugins: { legend: { position: 'top', }, }, }, };

    new Chart(myChart, config);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I missing?

I tried using different versions of the Chart.JS library, and it seems to work on versions 2.x

Here's a jsfiddle with the same issue: https://jsfiddle.net/oekt3v5c/

Comment: Remove `type="module"`?

Answer (score 0):

`<script type="module"` have a default scope of the *module level* and not the *global level*.

---

Follow [the getting started guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/) if you want to use Chart as a global:

> ```
> <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
> ```

Comment: Thanks @Quentin it worked!
So we shouldn't use CDNJS?
I tried also https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.3.2/chart.js
But then I get these errors:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at chart.js:7:1)
Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined

Comment: `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.3.2/chart.js` is an ECMAScript module. It needs to be loaded with `type="module"` **and used as a module**. It is not designed to be loaded without `type="module"` and create a global.